# Discord python bot - Commands not updating JSON databases

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to create a Discord bot in python with some JSON integration. I'm very new at this, so i've been following some tutorials and reading other bot's code.

I have 4 commands that use JSON to store data and read data, from a JSON file specific to each Discord Guild that the bot is connected to. But the commands aren't working, and don't update the data bases. The objective is that the command gather's the information and stores it for future callback with the other commands.

All four commands give me this error:

[Error when running command in Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riJZh.png)

The code for the four commands is this (sorry in advance for the extensive code):

```
# Adds a quote to the Database
@bot.command()
async def addquote(ctx):
    with open(str(bot.guilds) + ".json", 'r') as infile:
        parsed_json = json.load(infile)

    quote = ctx.quote.replace('.addquote', '') # Removes the command from the message
    length = AddRecord(parsed_json, ctx.author, quote, ctx.timestamp.date()) # Update local variable holding json
    UpdateDB(parsed_json, str(bot.guilds) + ".json") # Rewrite to file
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "quote {} added".format(length))

# Adds a quote with name to the Database
@bot.command()
async def addquotename(ctx):
    with open(str(bot.guilds) + ".json", 'r') as infile:
        parsed_json = json.load(infile)

    quote = ctx.content.replace("!addquotewithname ", "") # Removes the command from the message
    name = quote.split(' ')[0]
    quote = quote.replace(name + " ", "")
    length = AddRecordWithName(parsed_json, name, ctx.author, quote, ctx.timestamp.date()) # Update local variable holding json
    UpdateDB(parsed_json, str(bot.guilds) + ".json") # Rewrite to file
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "quote '{}' added".format(name))

# Gives a random quote from the Database
@bot.command()
async def randomquote(ctx):
    with open(str(bot.guilds) + ".json", 'r') as infile:
        parsed_json = json.load(infile)
    num = random.randint(1, len(parsed_json["quotes"]) - 1)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "quote " + str(num) + ": " + parsed_json["quotes"][str(num)]["content"])

# This command informs who added the quote to the Database
@bot.command()
async def quoteaddedby(ctx):
    data = ctx.content.replace("!quoteaddedby", "")
    try:
        with open(str(bot.guilds) + ".json", 'r') as infile:
            parsed_json = json.load(infile)
        quotenum = int(data)
        if quotenum > len(parsed_json["quotes"]):
            print(len(parsed_json["quotes"]))
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Number too large, there are {} quotes".format(len(parsed_json["quotes"]) - 1))
            return
        await client.send_message(message.channel, parsed_json["quotes"][str(quotenum)]["addedby"])
    except ValueError:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Error - quote requested must be by number")
```

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you think `str(bot.guilds)` returns? I would suggest having a single json file with keys and values instead of making new json files with dynamic names

Comment: Hi! By using str(bot.guilds) that it would open the specific file to store the data provided to the command. As I said, I'm pretty new at this so i'm trying to learn. I'm going to try and find another solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If all of the commands return the same error code, it's definitely worth looking into. `OSError [Errno 22]` should be a massive hint.

It usually means the path given to retrieve the file is not valid.

```
with open(str(bot.guilds) + ".json", 'r') as infile:
    parsed_json = json.load(infile)
```

`open()` is trying to open a file on your storage device, and it can't find `str(bot.guilds) + ".json"` file, or unable to process the file name.
This doesn't sound like it returned a right path. Either rename your JSON file to something more concrete, or make sure `str(bot.guilds)` is what you want.
Check if your paths to the JSON files are valid.